# Hibernate Stored procedure call maps values sequentially, not by parameter names

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures

We are calling stored procedure from hibernate using following code:

```
ProcedureCall procedureCall = session.createStoredProcedureCall("StoredProcedureName", CustomEntity.class);

procedureCall.registerParameter("ParameterName1",String.class,ParameterMode.IN);
        procedureCall.getParameterRegistration("ParameterName1")
                .bindValue("Value1");
procedureCall.registerParameter("ParameterName2",String.class,ParameterMode.IN);
        procedureCall.getParameterRegistration("ParameterName2")
                .bindValue("Value2");
```

Here, it is expected that it should map parameters with values by name. 
But it looks like it is mapping the values sequentially.
Because if we put a condition that if "value" is empty then skip the register parameter for that value. So, if we skip any parameter in between, then it maps values of it's next registered parameter with that skipped parameter.

Ex:

```
if (!value1.equals(""))
{
procedureCall.registerParameter("ParameterName1",String.class,ParameterMode.IN);
        procedureCall.getParameterRegistration("ParameterName1")
                .bindValue("Value1");
}
```

(that means if we get "value1" empty, then we will skip registering that parameter, but in this case, it will map "value2" to "parametername1")

How it can be avoided?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to call your stored procedure using the annotation `@NamedNativeQueries` in your `CustomEntity.class` like this:

```
@NamedNativeQueries(
    {
        @NamedNativeQuery(
              name = "storedProcedureName",
              query = "EXEC StoredProcedureName :ParameterName1, :ParameterName2",
              resultClass = CustomEntity.class
        )
    }
)
```

Then in your stored procedures caller class you can create a method that receives a `HashMap <String, Object>` where you will put your parameters by `<name, value>` tuples. Remember that you must put all parameters, if you dont need an specific parameter in some situation, send an empty string or a null value. For example the following method:

```
public <T> List<T> execPAmultipleResults(String paNamedQuery, HashMap<String, Object> parameters) {
        NativeQuery nativeQuery = currentSession.getNamedNativeQuery(paNamedQuery);
        if (parameters != null) {
            Set<String> params = parameters.keySet();
            params.stream().forEach((param) -> {
                Object obj = parameters.get(param);
                nativeQuery.setParameter(param, obj);
            });
        }
        return nativeQuery.list();
    }
```

You can send a null value for the `HashMap` argument when you execute a stored procedure without input parameters.